# fs.createReadStream() at specific position of file

Tags: node.js, seek, random-access

Is it possible to create a stream that reads from a specific position of file in node.js?

I know that I could use a more traditional fs.open / seek / read API, but in that case I need to somehow wrap them in a stream for underlying layers of my application.

Answer (score 14):

`fs.createReadStream()` has an option you can pass it to specify the start position for the stream.

```
let f = fs.createReadStream("myfile.txt", {start: 1000});
```

You could also open a normal file descriptor with `fs.open()`, then `fs.read()` one byte from a position right before where you want the stream to be positioned using the position argument to `fs.read()` and then you can pass that file descriptor into `fs.createReadStream()` as an option and the stream will start with that file descriptor and position (though obviously the `start` option to `fs.createReadStream()` is a bit simpler).

Comment: Theoretically I can use that to stream a audio file starting from a specific position, right?

Comment: @cheesyeyes - That depends.  If you're looking for an [audio-streaming protocol](http://www.garymcgath.com/streamingprotocols.html), a node.js stream is not that all by itself.  If you're looking to just deliver a certain set of bytes from a file, then a node.js stream could do that.